# UrlFetchApp.fetch: How to run in user's browser context?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am coding for Google Appscript to be used in a Google Sheet.

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` runs using a Http client located on a Google server. How do I run a Http fetch from the same browser context that has the Google Sheet opened?

The url I have to fetch data from requires logging in, so I would rather let the user log in first in another tab so that the browser context can be used for access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run `UrlfetchApp`  client side. To make connections client side, use plain JavaScript in a sidebar or a modal dialog.

One place to start: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html

Comment: @OldGeezer Feel free to edit the link in.